# SQL Server 2000 Cross Tab Multiple Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 tables that I want to dynamically generate an output but I need tables `grade` and `sport` to have its rows converted into columns. The following tables provided have sample data.

**student**

[image]

**grade**

[image]

**enrol**

[image]

**sport**

[image]

and this my desired output:

[image]

The output displays the students who enrolled under teacher 91 and shows all the sports (as columns) with its corresponding grade on sy 2014. Again, we are using SQL Server 2000 (and I think I should feel bad about it). I have tried lots of queries I found on the internet but it's not working.. and usually it is statically made (if you already know what columns you want to display).

Cross Tab itself is a little bit handy and I am making it more complicated with multiple tables. I have this problem for over 3 months now and I still haven't succeeded to achieve my desired output. By the way, I am coding it on `SqlDataSource` in ASP.Net and bind it on a `GridView`.

Comment: The only way to do this is if you don't know the sports names before hand is with dynamic sql.  Use one of the answers below and generate the sum lines and join lines dynamically from the table to a string variable and exec it.

Comment: I tried doing dynamic sql but it keeps on popping out errors like undeclared variable whatever.. is it working with SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SQL 2000 version:**

```
DECLARE @dynamicCols VARCHAR(8000);
SET @dynamicCols = '';

SELECT @dynamicCols = @dynamicCols+ 
       ', SUM(CASE WHEN sport.sportid='''+sportid+''' THEN grade.grade END) AS ['+sport+'] '
FROM sport

EXECUTE ( 
      'SELECT student.idnumber AS ID, student.student AS Student '
      +@dynamicCols+
      'FROM student
       JOIN grade on student.idnumber=grade.idnumber
       JOIN enrol on enrol.sportid=grade.sportid
       JOIN sport on sport.sportid=enrol.sportid 
       WHERE enrol.teacher=''91'' AND enrol.sy=''2014''
       GROUP BY student.idnumber, student.student
       ORDER BY student.student')
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

OK, since no one has stepped forward I will show you how I would do it dynamically.

Based on [YOusaFZai's template of doing it by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23487602/215752), first you create the dynamic items in the select list, then you merge them to the rest of the select statement, and finally you exec this dynamic statement:

```
DECLARE @sqlSTR VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @dynamicCols VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @dynamicCols = 
(
  SELECT ', SUM(CASE WHEN sport.sportid='''+sportid+''' THEN grade.grade END) AS ['+sport+'] '
  FROM sport
  FOR XML PATH('')
)

--PRINT @dynamicCols

SELECT @sqlSTR = 
      'SELECT student.idnumber AS ID, student.student AS Student '+@dynamicCols+
      'FROM student
       JOIN grade on student.idnumber=grade.idnumber
       JOIN enrol on enrol.sportid=grade.sportid
       JOIN sport on sport.sportid=enrol.sportid 
       WHERE enrol.teacher=''91'' AND enrol.sy=''2014''
       GROUP BY student.idnumber, student.student
       ORDER BY student.student'

EXEC(@sqlSTR)
```

**ADVANCED**

Sometimes you might expect bad data and you can protect yourself.  For example, if it is possible for the grade table to have sport ids which are not in the sport table you could change the first query like the following to include the bad data in the results:

```
SELECT @dynamicCols = 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ', SUM(CASE WHEN grade.sportid='''+grade.sportid+''' THEN grade.grade END) AS ['+ISNULL(sport.sport,'ILLEGAL ID #'+grade.sportid)+'] '
  FROM grade
  LEFT JOIN sport ON sport.sportid = grade.sportid
  FOR XML PATH('')
)
```

Comment: The code you provided works on MSSQL Server 2005 (but still has bugs) but when I tried it on Server 2000 (which is the version I am working with), and it isn't good. There says that there are undeclared something. But still, this is a very big help for me. I am trying to modify it and try to run it on SQL server 2000. Thank you Sir!

Comment: @eirishainjel -- an undeclared what?

Comment: @eirishainjel - It does not have bugs on 2005 with the data you gave.  Maybe you did not copy it correctly?

Comment: Seems like SQL Server 2000 doesn't accept VARCHAR(MAX), I already fixed those undeclared errors. Now, the last errors are **Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'Select'** and **Incorrect syntax near 'XML'**. I just copied the code you gave and it has these errors.

Comment: @eirishainjel - I posted a SQL 2000 version above, but I was not able to test this since I don't have a 2000 install and I'm not about to install it to test this answer :D

Comment: Sir, this indeed is a big help for future references. Updating my SQL Server 2000 to 2005 would be one of my choice since the code you provided perfectly runs on SQL Server 2005. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Hogan close bracket of `Execute` statement is missing for first query.

Comment: @Wulworine - Thanks for the heads up.  Just to be as nit-picky as you; that is called a parenthesis not a bracket. :)

Comment: yeah, exactly @Hogan :)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2000 (which does not support the PIVOT operator), cross tab pivot queries are usually constructed using aggregate functions like `MAX`.  Here is a view definition that produces the structure you need.  Note that your sport columns must be fully enumerated for all possible values of grade.sportid (the value 'spo99' was added to demonstrate).

```
CREATE VIEW StudentSportsGrades
AS
SELECT s.idnumber, s.student, sp.teacher
,   MAX(CASE WHEN g.sportid=N'spo1' THEN g.grade END) AS [Soccer]
,   MAX(CASE WHEN g.sportid=N'spo17' THEN g.grade END) AS [Tennis]
,   MAX(CASE WHEN g.sportid=N'spo3' THEN g.grade END) AS [Chess]
,   MAX(CASE WHEN g.sportid=N'spo99' THEN g.grade END) AS [SomeOtherSport]
FROM Student AS s
INNER JOIN grade AS g ON g.idnumber=s.idnumber
INNER JOIN sport AS sp ON sp.sportid=g.sportid
GROUP BY s.idnumber, s.student, sp.teacher
GO
```

Here is a query that produces the results that you need.

```
SELECT idnumber, student, Soccer, Tennis, Chess
FROM StudentSportsGrades
WHERE teacher=91
ORDER BY student
```

This is a static construction, so it may be the same as other examples you have seen in your search.  But wrapping it in a view provides some opportunity to produce results with varied columns and filter conditions.

See also [Crosstab Query in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423743/crosstab-query-in-sql-server-2000) which links to ways to use dynamic SQL to achieve this.

Comment: I already know and tried this code but I realized it isn't what I needed because as stated on my question, the sports are dynamically "created". Meaning, depending on the SY, sports will possibly changed and every student is taking different sports. But thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the columns soccer,Tennis and chess static.

```
select s.idnumber,student,
sum(case when sp.sportid='spo1' then grade end) as soccer
,sum(case when sp.sportid='spo17' then grade end) as Tennis
,sum(case when sp.sportid='spo3' then grade end) as Chess
from student s 
inner join grade g on s.idnumber=g.idnumber
inner join enrol e on e.sportid=g.sportid
inner join sport sp on sp.sportid=e.sportid and sp.sy=e.sy 
where sp.teacher='91'
group by s.idnumber,student
```

Comment: I already know and tried this code but I realized it isn't what I needed because as stated on my question, the sports are dynamically "created". Meaning, depending on the SY, sports will possibly changed and every student is taking different sports. But thanks anyway. :)